# How to implement a search bar into a currency converter app Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, searchbar

I'm trying to implement a search bar into my currency converter app. But the problem is I'm parsing the data from JSON using API and I don't know how to connect currency abbreviation with my search bar. I did try to hardcode all the currency abbreviation into an array, but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Here's the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

struct Currency: Decodable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [String : Double]
}

@IBOutlet weak var rateField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var conversionTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var eur: Currency?
var baseRate = 1.0
var data = ["AED","AFN","ALL","AMD","ANG","AOA","ARS","ATS","AUD","AWG","AZN","BAM","BBD","BDT","BEF","BGN","BHD","BIF","BMD","BND","BOB","BRL","BSD","BTN","BWP","BYR","BZD","CAD","CDF","CHF","CLP","CNY","COP","COU","CRC","CUC","CUP","CVE","CZK","DEM","DJF","DKK","DOP","DZD","EEK","EGP","ERN","ESP","ETB","EUR","FIM","FJD","FKP","FRF","GBP","GEL","GHS","GIP","GMD","GNF","GRD","GTQ","GYD","HKD","HNL","HRK","HTG","HUF","IDR","IEP","ILS","INR","IQD","IRR","ISK","ITL","JMD","JOD","JPY","KES","KGS","KHR","KMF","KPW","KRW","KWD","KYD","KZT","LAK","LBP","LKR","LRD","LSL","LTL","LUF","LVL","LYD","MAD","MDL","MGA","MKD","MMK","MNT","MOP","MRO","MUR","MVR","MWK","MXN","MYR","MZN","NAD","NGN","NIO","NLG","NOK","NPR","NZD","OMR","PAB","PEN","PGK","PHP","PKR","PLN","PTE","PYG","QAR","RON","RSD","RUB","RWF","SAR","SBD","SCR","SDG","SEK","SGD","SHP","SIT","SLL","SOS","SRD","STD","SVC","SYP","SZL","THB","TJS","TMT","TND","TOP","TRY","TTD","TWD","TZS","UAH","UGX","USD","UYI","UYU","UZS","VEF","VND","VUV","WST","XAF","XCD","XDR","XOF","XPF","YER","ZAR","ZMK","ZWL"]

var filteredData: [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    searchBar.delegate = self
    filteredData = data
    
    rateField.round()
    conversionTableView.round()
    button.round()
    
    conversionTableView.dataSource = self
    conversionTableView.delegate = self
    conversionTableView.allowsSelection = false
    
    fetchData()
}

@IBAction func onConvertButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if let iGetString = rateField.text {
        if let isDouble = Double(iGetString) {
            baseRate = isDouble
            fetchData()
        } else {
            let alertControl = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong data!", message: "Please, use digits only!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
            alertControl.addAction(cancelAction)
            present(alertControl, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func fetchData() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?=EUR")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.eur = try JSONDecoder().decode(Currency.self, from: data!)
            } catch {
                print("Parse Error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.conversionTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let currencyFetched = eur {
        return currencyFetched.rates.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    if let currencyFetched = eur {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Array(currencyFetched.rates.keys)[indexPath.row]
        let selectedRate = baseRate * Array(currencyFetched.rates.values)[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(String(format: "%.2f", selectedRate))"
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = []
    if searchText == "" {
        filteredData = data
    } else {
        for currency in data {
            if currency.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                filteredData.append(currency)
            }
        }
    }
    self.conversionTableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Comment: can you share more details, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @DeepakSingh when I type any currency abbreviation into my search bar the typed currency doesn't show up in my tableViewCell(The tableView becomes empty). I think I shouldn't use an array of the hardcoded  currency abbreviations, the dataSource should be taken from the JSON in this case, but I have no idea how to implement it...

Comment: "Single source of truth" to use a popular phrase. You should not have a second array `data` and instead search your downloaded data. Looks like `eur.rates.keys` is what you want to search but personally I would use a different struct than that for my data.

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson, You should use single source of truth. try filtering from data you fetched from you API call rather than the new array constant you made.

Comment: @NikolaiBorisov were you able to fix it?

Comment: @DeepakSingh Nope =(